# Float to string using PIC16F1824

Tags: c, uart, pic

I have some trouble using a PIC16F1824.
I want to convert an value retrieve from the ADC converter and transmit it to an UART.
I've used MCC to generate my code.
When I debug my code step by step, the voltage value is similar that the one I've obtained with my scope.
But when I want to print this value on the serial interface, I have an error with the argument %f (or %.2f) in printf.

> C:\Program
> Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.20\pic\sources\c99\common\nf_fputc.c:16::
> warning: (1498) pointer (unknown) in expression may have no targets
> C:\Program
> Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.20\pic\sources\c99\common\doprnt.c:66:: error:
> (1250) could not find space (80 bytes) for variable _dbuf (908) exit
> status = 1

Here is my code

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"

void main(void) {
    SYSTEM_Initialize();

    uint16_t convertedValue, convertedValue2;
    float voltage, voltage2;
    float temp = 0;
    volatile float sensorRH = 0;
    char buffer[5];
    
    while (1) {
        //                 ADC_SelectChannel(channel_AN0);
        //        ADC_StartConversion();
        //        while (!ADC_IsConversionDone());
        //        convertedValue = ADC_GetConversionResult();
        //        voltage = convertedValue * 0.0048875;
        //        temp = (voltage2 - 0.424) / 0.00625; // LM60

        ADC_SelectChannel(channel_AN2);
        ADC_StartConversion();
        while (!ADC_IsConversionDone());
        convertedValue2 = ADC_GetConversionResult();
        voltage2 = convertedValue2 * 0.0048875; // Tension 5V - Résolution 10 bits (5/1023)   
        sensorRH = (voltage2 - 0.852) / 0.031483; // HIH-4000
        
        printf("ADC converted value = %.2f\n", sensorRH);               
        sprintf(buffer, "%f",sensorRH);
        
    }
}
```

I've also tried to :

- include stdio lib : `#include <stdio.h>`
- change the float value to a `volatile float sensorRH;`
- declare my float outside the main function. This gave me an other error :

> C:\Program
> Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.20\pic\sources\c99\common\nf_fputc.c:16::
> warning: (1498) pointer (unknown) in expression may have no targets
> mcc_generated_files/eusart.c:64:: error: (1250) could not find space
> (8 bytes) for variable _eusartTxBuffer (908) exit status = 1

- try the sprintf function with different size of buffer (same error than the first one).

I'm using a PIC16F1824 with a PIC4kit debugger and XC8 compiler.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `char buffer[5];`: 5 looks a bit short to me, try `char buffer[20];` and report back.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a float? You could transmit the value using an integer and make the calculation on the other host, it would make it a bit easier. Or calculate the temperature in 0.01 °C or so.

Comment: You do not have enough RAM. Try making the program simpler (not using float since float is expensive on a PIC16).

Comment: If this is a hobby project, I would recommend taking a trash bin and putting there all pic* stuff with the buggy xc8 compiler and buying cheaper stm32 chips. If not, I recommend to remove all `float` variable in your code and use only integer arithmetic, preferably code in Q number format. Printing floats is hard and costly - I wouldn't go with printing floats on such a small target.

Comment: you almost never want to use sprintf/printf in embedded-land. It takes an arm and a leg of ram to run. It's easier to just manually code ftoa/itoa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I send my ADC values in millivolt over the UART and make the conversion on the PC software.
It's not really clean, but it do the job...
Thanks

```
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;
 while (1) {
        ADC_SelectChannel(channel_AN2);
        ADC_StartConversion();
        while (!ADC_IsConversionDone());
        convertedValue = ADC_GetConversionResult();
        voltage = convertedValue * 0.0048875;
        i = voltage * 100;
       
        __delay_ms(500);                    
        
        ADC_SelectChannel(channel_AN3);     
        ADC_StartConversion();
        while (!ADC_IsConversionDone());
        convertedValue2 = ADC_GetConversionResult();
        voltage2 = convertedValue2 * 0.0048875; 
        j = voltage2 * 100;
            
        printf("ADC voltage = %1u - %1u\r\n", i, j);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you get means you have either not enough RAM or Flash, or in other words you use too much space. A very simple way to reduce space by a small amount is by enabling optimizer. A way to reduce more is by writing code that does not require so much space. The `printf()` family takes a significant amount of space and floating point also. If you can do not use `printf()` or `sprintf()` and replace the floating point operations with integer operations, this should be possible but it may give you a bit less precise calculations which should not matter since your ADC is not very precise to begin with.

Comment: `you a bit less precise` I would argue that more precise. Floating point numbers are not precise, they loose precision depending on exponent. Integers are as precise as they can get and you can easily exactly predict all value range and pick integers big enough to exactly represent the thing you want to represent.

Comment: @KamilCuk Both `float` and `int` are exact according to the specification/how to program them. But when i replace `float` with `int` (or `long`, `uin32_t`, whatever) i don't use the few highest bits most of the time, so that i am sure i never get an overflow, with that i waste space and i lose more information,by not using all of it, this is different from a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

To address the diagnostic message from the compiler:

```
C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.20\pic\sources\c99\common\nf_fputc.c:16:: warning: (1498) pointer (unknown) in expression may have no targets 
 
C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.20\pic\sources\c99\common\doprnt.c:66:: error: (1250) could not find space (80 bytes) for variable _dbuf (908) exit status = 1
```

The first one "warning: (1498)" is a generated because the XC8 compiler is stupid when handling what's sometimes called opaque pointers. But since this is in reference to Microchip library code that you should not change and the code is in fact correct just ignore this warning.

The second one "error: (1250)" is an error in your code. You have declared more object than there is available RAM for.

This is code I just created for you that uses only integer math:

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"

/*
                         Main application
 */
void main(void)
{
#define VREF_VALUE (500)   // ADC VREF voltage in 1/100 of a volt
    uint32_t convertedValue2;
    uint16_t voltage2;
    
    // initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();

    // When using interrupts, you need to set the Global and Peripheral Interrupt Enable bits
    // Use the following macros to:

    // Enable the Global Interrupts
    //INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable();

    // Enable the Peripheral Interrupts
    //INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable();

    // Disable the Global Interrupts
    //INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptDisable();

    // Disable the Peripheral Interrupts
    //INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptDisable();

    while (1)
    {
        // Add your application code
        ADC_SelectChannel(channel_AN2);
        __delay_ms(1000);
        ADC_StartConversion();
        while (!ADC_IsConversionDone());
        convertedValue2 = ADC_GetConversionResult();
        voltage2 = (uint16_t)( (convertedValue2 * VREF_VALUE + 0x8000ul) >> 16 );
        printf("ADC voltage = %1u.%02u\r\n", voltage2/100, voltage2%100);
    }
}
```

As you have not provided any details on the sensor that you are using I cannot show you the integer math to do scaling and offset specific to your sensor.

The complete MPLABX v5.40 project an be found on my git hub repository [here](https://github.com/dsoze1138/16F1824_ADC_printf_v540).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answers.
I think I understand the advice, convert the value in integer and then divide it to get a float value in the serial interface.
I just have a problem with this line

```
voltage2 = (uint16_t)( (convertedValue2 * VREF_VALUE + 0x8000ul) >> 16 );
```

It give me something wrong
[image]

I'm using the sensors

[LM60](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm60.pdf)
[HIH-4000](https://sensing.honeywell.com/honeywell-sensing-hih4000-series-product-sheet-009017-5-en.pdf)

I've made the conversion with this code

```
voltage = convertedValue * 0.0048875; // VREF : 5V / 10 bits ADC    
temp = (voltage - 0.424) / 0.00625; // LM60   
sensorRH = (voltage - 0.852) / 0.031483; // HIH-4000
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: "It give me something wrong" What does it give you? Your debugger is paused before you calculate `voltage2`. What is the value after?

Comment: I have 0x0003 for voltage2, I place the debugger a step after the printf. My voltage value is normally 2.18V (my convertedValue2 is 0x000001BF)